# Changing user agent string in a http request in R

Tags: url, r, httpwebrequest, http-headers, user-agent

How does one change user agent strings in http requests made in R? And how do I figure out what my current user agent string looks like?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`options("HTTPUserAgent")` or `getOption("HTTPUserAgent")` prints your current settings, and `options(HTTPUserAgent="My settings")` is the way to change it.

To temporary change this option use: `withr::with_options`:

```
withr::with_options(list(HTTPUserAgent="My settings"), download.file(..something..))
```

or [Droplet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536835/changing-user-agent-string-in-a-http-request-in-r/61505335#61505335) if you use `download.file`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution using `options()` in the accepted answer will change the setting globally for the whole session (unless you change it back).

To change the User-Agent temporarily in a request made by [`download.file()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html), you need to use the `headers` argument:

```r
download.file("https://httpbin.org/user-agent", 
              destfile = "test.txt", 
              headers = c("User-Agent" = "My Custom User Agent"))
```

Since R 4.0.0, you can also use this argument in [`available.packages()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/available.packages.html) and [`install.packages()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html) and it will be forwarded to `download.file()`.

Comment: Where can I find suitable user agent strings for this?