# How can I fix a 403 Forbidden error when attempting web-scraping in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

403 Forbidden error message when trying to access Congressional Record

I tried this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

# Functions
get_urls_in_table <- function(master_link) {
  with_user_agent <- GET(master_link, add_headers('user-agent' = 'name@xxx.edu'))
  links <- read_html(with_user_agent) %>% html_nodes("td a") %>% html_attr('href') %>% as.data.frame()
  return(links)
}

get_content <- function(x) {
  with_user_agent <- GET(x, add_headers('user-agent' = 'name@xxx.edu'))
  content <- read_html(with_user_agent) %>% html_nodes(".styled") %>% html_text()
  print("getting content")
  Sys.sleep(30) # Here add 30 sec between each scraping attempt to prevent the queries from becoming too frequent
  return(content)
}

# Layer 1
senate_pages <- get_urls_in_table("https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/108th-congress/browse-by-date")

senate_pages <- senate_pages %>%
  mutate(real_url = paste("https://www.congress.gov", ., sep = "")) %>%
  filter(grepl("senate",real_url))

# Layer 2
senate_articles <- lapply(senate_pages$real_url[1:2],get_urls_in_table) 
# Here I only ran the first two issues, but this should work for all if you get rid of [1:2]

senate_articles <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, senate_articles)) %>% # Take data frames out of lists
  mutate(real_url = paste("https://www.congress.gov", ., sep = "")) %>%
  filter(grepl("article",real_url))

# Layer 3
senate_content <- lapply(senate_articles$real_url[1:3],get_content)
# Again only running the first few, but should work on a larger scale
senate_content <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, senate_content)) # Data clean should follow this
```

And got the 403 Forbidden error message. I have tried to change the user agent to different names without any success, including my actual email address (and not the name@xxx.edu used in the code above), the name of my thesis, my name, and my name with spaces before my email address. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I think this is probably a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536835/changing-user-agent-string-in-a-http-request-in-r

Comment: There's a Cloudflare javascript-based challange - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXOTu.png  , rvest / httr2 / curl (from command line) are all triggering this even when all the cookies and rest of the headers (inc. user-agent) are copied from valid browser session. Chromote can get though once useragent is updated.

Comment: I have never used Chromote before. Would I just use something like the following added to the existing code? @margusl

`code` library(chromote)

b <- ChromoteSession$new()
# Display the current session in the Chromote browser:
# b$view()

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Chromote doc provides quite nice walk though to get it up and running and it does not require jumping though loops like it's often the case with Selenium / RSelenium. Though for whatever reason  `b$view()` hasn't been working for some time starting from some unknown Chrome version, at least not for me.

Comment: Actually the issue with `view()` and affected Chrome versions are known  - https://github.com/rstudio/chromote/issues/99

Comment: Thanks for your help @margusl it was a tremendous help. Now I can run a function on a dataframe object to pull text content and create a new dataframe from it (dataframe w/rows representing each section of the total document and one column w/the cell values being the text in the section). If I run more than twice, the function holds zero values. If I close R Studio, reload my environment, rerun the libraries and custom functions, I can run the function on 2 more objects to create the dataframes, but the problem then comes back. With 299 objects, I am hoping to find a way around it.

Comment: Maybe it's a CPU/RAM problem regarding computer limitations? I might need to make this a new question to put in all of the code and a screenshot of my global environment. Below is the line that stops working with associated output that should be coming up:

`senate_content <- lapply(senate_articles$real_url,get_content)
#> [1] "getting content"
#> [1] "getting content"
#> [1] "getting content"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That 403 response actually includes a Cloudflare javascript-based challange ([screenshot forom Chromote session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXOTu.png)) and it's quite effective with blocking static scrapers and HTTP request tools like `httr(2)` and  `revest`.

But it also detects `curl` requests with fully configured headers (i.e. *Copy as cURL* call from browser's dev tools; and there we have user agent, cookies and other headers cloned from our fully functional browser session).

Though [Chromote](https://github.com/rstudio/chromote), once it's unique user-agent is updated, is currently able to get through (with default user-agent it would still trigger that js challenge). In the example bellow I only included Chromote session handling and replaced `httr::GET()` calls with Chromote calls. And I wasn't so keen on waiting 30 seconds between requests... BTW, nice reproducible example there, no additional changes were required! :)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

### update /
library(chromote)
# new sessio, set userAgent, value grabbed from current Chrome wof Windows
b <- ChromoteSession$new()
b$Network$setUserAgentOverride(userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
#> named list()
### / update 

# Functions
get_urls_in_table <- function(master_link) {
  ### update /
  {
    b$Page$navigate(master_link)
    b$Page$loadEventFired()
  } 
  with_user_agent <- b$Runtime$evaluate("document.querySelector('html').outerHTML")$result$value
  ### / update
  links <- read_html(with_user_agent) %>% html_nodes("td a") %>% html_attr('href') %>% as.data.frame()
  return(links)
}

get_content <- function(x) {
  ### update /  
  {
    b$Page$navigate(x)
    b$Page$loadEventFired()
  } 
  with_user_agent <- b$Runtime$evaluate("document.querySelector('html').outerHTML")$result$value
  ### / update
  content <- read_html(with_user_agent) %>% html_nodes(".styled") %>% html_text()
  print("getting content")
  # Sys.sleep(30) # Here add 30 sec between each scraping attempt to prevent the queries from becoming too frequent
  return(content)
}

# Layer 1
senate_pages <- get_urls_in_table("https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/108th-congress/browse-by-date")

senate_pages <- senate_pages %>%
  mutate(real_url = paste("https://www.congress.gov", ., sep = "")) %>%
  filter(grepl("senate",real_url))

# Layer 2
senate_articles <- lapply(senate_pages$real_url[1:2],get_urls_in_table) 
# Here I only ran the first two issues, but this should work for all if you get rid of [1:2]

senate_articles <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, senate_articles)) %>% # Take data frames out of lists
  mutate(real_url = paste("https://www.congress.gov", ., sep = "")) %>%
  filter(grepl("article",real_url))

# Layer 3
senate_content <- lapply(senate_articles$real_url[1:3],get_content)
#> [1] "getting content"
#> [1] "getting content"
#> [1] "getting content"
# Again only running the first few, but should work on a larger scale
senate_content <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, senate_content)) # Data clean should follow this

### update /
# close Chromote session
b$close()
#> [1] TRUE
```

Result:

```r
# senate_content:
as_tibble(senate_content)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>   V1                                                                            
#>   <chr>                                                                         
#> 1 "\n[Pages S12089-S12092]\nFrom the Congressional Record Online through the Go…
#> 2 "\n[Page S12092]\nFrom the Congressional Record Online through the Government…
#> 3 "\n[Pages S12092-S12093]\nFrom the Congressional Record Online through the Go…

# beginning of the 1st article:
cat(substr(senate_content[1,1],1,400))
#> 
#> [Pages S12089-S12092]
#> From the Congressional Record Online through the Government Publishing Office [www.gpo.gov]
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> 
#>                           OFFSHORE OUTSOURCING
#> 
#>   Mr. LIEBERMAN. Mr. President, on December 15, 2004, my office 
#> released a white paper entitled ``Data Dearth in Offshore Outsourcing: 
#> Policymaking Requires Facts.'' This white paper is closely linked to a 
#> previous white paper ent
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>